# Merging two commands into one

Tags: spacing, merge

I want to merge `\textdelta` and `\,` into one command, called `\tdelta`.

Package: `\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}`

I know that I can use `\let\tdelta\textdelta`, but I also want a space after that (`\,`).

Comment: Did you try `\newcommand\tdelta{\textdelta\,}`?

Comment: Uh, `\newcommand{\tdelta}{\textdelta \,}` – am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(following up on a suggestion I made in a comment...)

> I want to merge `\textdelta` and `\,` into one command, called `\tdelta`.

I can suggest

```
\newcommand{\tdelta}{\textdelta\,}
```